# php encode and decode row if know salt (not use mcrypt)

Tags: php, decode, encode

Good day.

Tell me please how encode/decode row if i know word and salt, for ex.:

```
$word = 'row=test&row2=link';
$salt = '42b&df';
```

I would like encode $word and decode code (get $word) if i know $salt.

How make it?

P.S.: not use mcrypt.

Comment: You would also need the key. `mcrypt` deals with encryption, not hashing, perhaps you mean `crypt`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$word = 'row=test&row2=link';
$key = "42b&df";

$encoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $word, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

echo $encoded.'<br>';

$decoded = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encoded), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

echo $decoded;
?>
```